# How to pass state.params from react-navigation as props in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to pass the props from

`this.props.navigation.navigate('LIST_PRODUCT', { product: item.product, stock: item.stock});`

but the result will be

```
{ 
 ...this.props,
 navigation: {
  ...,
  state: {
    ...,
    params: {
      product: 'Lenovo K5 Pro',
      stock: 5
    }
  }
 }
}
```

and the result what I want is

```
{ 
 ...this.props,
 product: 'Lenovo K5 Pro',
 stock: 5
}
```

is there any way to passing params from state to this.props in child component?

Comment: Seems like the standard way of passing state on a route change, they typically get packed in with the passed props to the new component on the new route, and thus, need to be accessed from the props object. If that isn't good enough I suppose you could wrap your route component to unpack/repack the props in the shape you prefer, but that's probably more work than it's worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the below solution

HomeScreen.js

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
        <Button
          title="Go to Details"
          onPress={() => {
            /* 1. Navigate to the Details route with params */
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', {
              itemId: 86,
              otherParam: 'anything you want here',
            });
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

DetailsScreen.js

```
class DetailsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    /* 2. Get the param, provide a fallback value if not available */
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const itemId = navigation.getParam('itemId', 'NO-ID');
    const otherParam = navigation.getParam('otherParam', 'some default value');

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Details Screen</Text>
        <Text>itemId: {JSON.stringify(itemId)}</Text>
        <Text>otherParam: {JSON.stringify(otherParam)}</Text>
        <Button
          title="Go to Details... again"
          onPress={() =>
            this.props.navigation.push('Details', {
              itemId: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
            })
          }
        />
        <Button
          title="Go to Home"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}
        />
        <Button
          title="Go back"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could just spread the state object like this:

```
const { navigation, ...rest } = this.props;
{
  ...rest,
  ...navigation.state.params
}
```

Beware that `state.params` may not always be there

Comment: @Randy Wardhana if this worked please put the star and the arrow help so it can help others!!